# How to generate Django / Python Test for view with LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am trying for some time to test a view of mine that I have protected from access via LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin.

Unfortunately I do not manage to write the appropriate test.

here is the view. The special thing is, that the user must not only be logged in, but he must also belong to the group "Administrator" or "Supervisor".

With this combination I have not yet managed to write a test.

Please who can help me. Here is my View:

```
class FeatureListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
model = FeatureFilm
template_name = "project/feature-list.html"

def test_func(self):
    if self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Administrator").exists():
        return True
    elif self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Supervisor").exists():
        return True
    elif self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Operator").exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def handle_no_permission(self):
    return redirect("access-denied")
```

and here is a snippet of the url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("feature/list/", FeatureListView.as_view(), name="feature-list"),
path(
    "feature/<int:pk>/date",
    FeatureDetailViewDate.as_view(),
    name="feature-detail-date",
),
```

how would you test this FeatureListView and the template belongs to

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would be better if you would give those groups a permission. Because django offers a lot nice functionalities to check for permissions rather than checking for groups (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions)). You would give Administrator, Supervisor and Operator all the same permission and then instead of checking if the user is in one of these groups, you would just check whether the user has that permission. But as that was not the question there you go:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client

class TestFeatureListView(TestCase):

def _create_administrator(self):
    u = Users.objects.create( <input for administrator> )
    u.groups.add(administrator)
    return u
def _create_supervisor(self):
    u = Users.objects.create( <input for supervisor> )
    u.groups.add(supervisor)
    return u
def _create_operator(self):
    u = Users.objects.create( <input for operator> )
    u.groups.add(operator)
    return u
def _create_normal_user(self):
    return Users.objects.create( <input for normal_user> )

def test_users_with_access_rights(self):
    users = [
        self._create_administrator(),
        self._create_supervisor(),
        self._create_operator(),
    ]
    for u in users:
        c = Client()  # initialize every iteration a new client
        c.login(username=<username>, password=<password>)
        response = c.get(reverse("appwithfeaturelist:feature-list"))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "project/feature-list.html")

def test_users_withOUT_access_rights(self):
    u = self._create_normal_user()
    self.client.login(username=<username>, password=<password>)
    response = self.client.get(reverse("appwithfeaturelist:feature-list"), follow=True)
    self.assertTemplateNotUsed(response, "project/feature-list.html")
    self.assertRedirects(response, "/access-denied/")

def test_without_any_user(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse("appwithfeaturelist:feature-list"), follow=True)
    self.assertTemplateNotUsed(response, "project/feature-list.html")
    self.assertRedirects(response, "/access-denied/") # this is probably wrong and should test whether the redirect goes to something like a login page
```